# Angular 4 - How much faster is Angular bundled with --prod

Tags: angular, performance

Due to our unfavorable software architecture in a .Net/Angular web application, we probably can't execute the bundling of ng build (--prod) for the production environment.

My question now is, how big is the performance gain from an Angular application loaded with *SystemJS* compared to the same application bundled with `ng build --prod`?

Has anyone performed a performance measurement?

I tried it with the following test application and read the execution time in the *Developer Console but this is not really reliable*. [angular-realworld-example-app](https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app)

"SystemJS" | "Bundled Prod"
.....1.9s....... |..........1.1s
.... 2.2s....... |..........1.4s
.....1.7s....... |..........1.3s
.....2.1s....... |..........1.0s
.....1.8s....... |..........1.1s
.....1.7s....... |..........1.15s

**...~1.68s..... |........~1.17s**
 (Average seconds)

Answer (score 4):

ng build --prod creates an "Ahead Of Time" bundle ( https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler ) which means that the angular compiler does not have to be included in the production bundle.

As written in the docs, there's performance gains in terms of download size:

> The compiler is roughly half of Angular itself, so omitting it dramatically reduces the application payload.

And also gains in application startup time:

> Faster rendering
>
> With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

The actual gain compared to a JIT compiled app depends on the amount of templates and their size.

> Fewer asynchronous requests
>
> The compiler inlines external HTML templates and CSS style sheets within the application JavaScript, eliminating separate ajax requests for those source files.

Comment: bit of a correction the --aot flag does Ahead of Time compilation, the --prod flag is a shortcut for --target=production

Comment: But isn't the --prod a meta flag that sets the --aot flag? (as written here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build )